# Get XAML UI element from JavaScript

Tags: silverlight

I've tried to Google for this but maybe I'm not forming my query right, 'cos I am getting a lot of nonsense and irrelevance back. Probably too simple a question. Apologies it's been a while since I last did Silverlight!

If I have a XAML element:

```
<Image Canvas.Top="128" x:Name="img4_7" Width="180.3" Height="117" Source="monkey1.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Left="-3.344" Opacity="0.595"/>
```

How can I get that in JavaScript using the x:Name? I'm looking for something like getElementById(), but for Silverlight. I almost want something like this:

```
img4_7=rootElement.children.getItem('img4_7');
```

Obviously, this doesn't work!

I'm not using ASP.NET AJAX.

Thanks for any help for this noob question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Need to use control.content.findName()

Here's my handLoad, for others to benefit:

```
handleLoad: function(control, userContext, rootElement) 
{
    this.control = control;

    // Sample event hookup: 
    rootElement.addEventListener("MouseLeftButtonDown", Silverlight.createDelegate(this, this.handleMouseDown));

    this.img4_7=control.content.findName("img4_7"); 

    if (this.img4_7) {
        this.img4_7.addEventListener("MouseEnter", Silverlight.createDelegate(this,this.handleMouseEnter));
        this.img4_7.addEventListener("MouseLeave",Silverlight.createDelegate(this,this.handleMouseLeave));

    }


},
```

Comment: Forgive me for bumping this old question. But I have the exact same situation as you, but it does not work...

I need this element:

<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}" Text="2321" x:Name="start_data_a" />

where x:Name is the unique name (have one for each start_data_letter)

Comment: Wow, this is an oldie! This question was for Silverlight 1, so I'm not sure if it is relevant with 2+ as these have differing architectures (they have "mini CLRs"). Maybe you're using 3/4 without realising it? I believe you can write a loader which behaves like Silverlight 1, if that is what you are targetting here? Otherwise, you'll need to either do what you need in the Silveright app itself, or leverage an alternative JS API for accessing the XAML DOM (of which I am currently unaware). Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Silverlight 1. But no worries, it's fixed by now.